# opensource SVG drawing program simpler than InkScape on Linux

Tags: linux, svg

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) is very powerful, but too complex for me, to make occasional drawings like [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/393837/40065).

Do you know some simpler alternatives (open source, for a Linux Debian desktop, to make *vector* not *bitmap* drawings), and compatible with a wacom pen. In an ideal world, something scriptable with [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) ? I googled and found [this](https://itsfoss.com/vector-graphics-editors-linux/).

It should be open source, because I might patch it (e.g. to add Guile scriptability)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [LibreOffice Draw](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/draw/)? It's a much smaller and simpler program than Inkscape, with more limited features, but it has all the basic drawing tools and primitives.

It supports SVG import and export. You can use a Wacom tablet with it, but I don't think it will detect things like pen pressure and tilt.